# Not able to integrate logstash with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, logstash

I want to send the output of logstash to mongodb for which I am using mongodb output plugins of logstash in linux. I am using logstash-1.5.0.beta1 and mongodb-3.0.3 versions. I am getting the following error :

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- mongo
        require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
        require at /root/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
        require at /root/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53
        require at /root/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65
       register at /root/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/lib/logstash/outputs/mongodb.rb:37
           each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
  start_outputs at /root/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:158
            run at /root/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:79
        execute at /root/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141
            run at /root/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/lib/logstash/runner.rb:166
           call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271
            run at /root/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/lib/logstash/runner.rb:171
           call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271
     initialize at /root/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.18/lib/stud/task.rb:12
```

My logstash conf file is as follows:

```
input {
        file{
                path => "/something.csv"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
                }
}

output { stdout {codec => rubydebug}
        mongodb{
                collection => "users"
                database => "test"
                uri => "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
        }
}
```

I run this using the command:

```
/root/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/logstash-mongodb.conf
```

Can anyone guide me to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are giving file name as -  path => "/something.csv"  -- logstash is not able to identify. Add absolute path to file input path as below, so that logstash can identify the location and process it.

```
input {
        file {
                path => "C://myfile/something.csv"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}
```

Comment: But, I am using a linux box and the file is placed under root that is "/".